# Signed WinXP driver shown as unsigned for normal users

Tags: laptop, drivers, privileges

On a Dell Latitude laptop model installed in our enterprise environment the "Intel Management Engine Interface" driver is loaded and works as expected, but on the driver tab in dev-manager it is said to be unsigned. This is not the case when a Admin is longed in, or when just running the dev-manager as an admin.

It is clear that this is just a "cosmetic" issue, but I feel the need to understand why this is.

Thank you for you help.

Comment: Are we talking about x86 or x64 Windows?  It sounds like thw two users are using different versions of the driver.  I would try installing the driver through the user account to see if that helps.

Comment: This is x86, the users are not using different drivers, even when I am logged in as the user and rund dev-manager as admin I get different results. I can have two instances of dev-manager running paralell (ona as user, one as admin) and get the different results.

Comment: Also: I can still check the version number of the "unsigned" driver, and it is the same as the one seen from an admins point of view.

Comment: Is there realy no one who experiences this? We have it on several modells now. I realise it nust be something we are doing wrong, but what?